# How is a "wipe effect" intellectually accomplished, animated DIRECTIONAL fade-in from left to right

Tags: animation

I don't understand what a "wipe effect" or DIRECTIONAL fade-in is "intellectually", what's happening when we see someone "do it."  To provide some context, here is my graphics environment:

Layer 3: if needed, I can use too  (please note the runtime graphics environment only allows "simple addition" of the layers, that's all.  I use GIMP to make images, the open source similar program to photoshop, but I don't care the tool, I'm tring to understand it intellectually).

Layer 2: this will be a smaller PNG image I want to do a "wipe effect" or DIRECTIONAL fade in, e.g. from left to right (or right to left), over the full background below.

Layer 1: this will be whatever full background image I want.

This environment (the canvas in html) allows adjusting the opacity (or alpha) value of the entire layer, and I have the code to do this over time (that's easy). My problem is, I don't understand "intellectually" what I need to do, to give the appearance of something (a png) image fading in "left to right".

E.g. if I were to create a gradiated black to alpha layer 3, I can do that too, but I think unless I make it exactly match the outline of the graphic I'm seeking to fade in, it will equally "disturb" the background, right? So ... how is this done "intellectually", please? Do I even need 3 layers, or is 2 fine? Thanks.

So, I can "write the code", I'm not looking for any "handouts" there; I'm struggling to intellectually see what I need to do, to produce this rather common type of animation.

Answer (score 0):

> if I were to create a gradiated black to alpha layer 3, I can do that too, but I think unless I make it exactly match the outline of the graphic I'm seeking to fade in, it will equally "disturb" the background, right?

No, because layer 3 is configured as a *mask* on layer 2. So it affects only layer 2, and affects only its transparency.

---

So, let’s say you start with a mask that is four times the width of layer 2. Construct the mask like this:

```
/ opaque /  grad  /  ient  / transp /
```

Section 1 is opaque, sections 2 and 3 are a gradient from opaque to transparent, and section 4 is transparent. Well then, start with this mask located with its right end touching the right end of layer 2. Then section 4 covers layer 2, so layer 2 is transparent and invisible. Now animate the mask rightwards until its  left end touches the left end of layer 2. Now section 1 covers layer 2, so layer 2 is opaque and fully visible.

In between, layer 2 faded in from left to right.

Here's a demonstration:

[image]

Notice that the text fades in from left to right, but the background color is unaffected.

Comment: matt, please refrain from placing in "answers", that are not answers.  And layer 3 is not configured anyway.  Do you know why it's good to refrain from doing that, especially as the first "answer"?  Because now, people looking at the question, will think, someone has given a shot to answer it, which as you can see, you have not.  So, you're hurting progress, by this type of action.

Comment: Html canvas only allows simple addition of layers, I'm 95% sure or higher.  Please delete your answer if possible, so "people" see this is unanswered.

Comment: So how does one create a gradient, that is opaque to transparent, AND DOES NOT ALSO have a color, in a tool like GIMP?

Comment: The colors don't matter. It's a _mask_. Only the transparency of any pixel matters. That is what a mask _is_. — Anyway, no "tools" were mentioned in your question. No computer languages either. You asked _intellectually_ how this is done. I explained it intellectually, and demonstrated that this approach works by using it to make a layer that fades in from left to right. When you see this being done, that is _how_ it is done. That is what you asked and that is what I explained to you.